# plotly: Map size (shape) to value colum in scatterplot

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization

I really appreaciate the 'plotly' r-package. Currently I run into an issue, where I want to visualize a data frame as points and map the point size (as well as the shape potentially) to a dimension of the data frame.

The problem I run into with my own dataset is, that the sizes are somehow "mixed up" in the sense, that the bigger points don't correspond to the bigger values.

I haven't fully understood the options I have with plotly (`sizeref` and other marker-options; the fundamental difference between mapping the dimension directly or in the marker arguments; etc) , so this is my best shot as a minimal example right here.

(The second plot is closer to what I currently do. If this one could be fixed, it would be preferable to me)

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated. :)

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x    = 1:10,
                 y    = rep(c("id1", "id2"), 5),
                 col  = factor(sample(3, 10, replace = TRUE)))
df$size <- c(40, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 10)

df
#>     x   y col size
#> 1   1 id1   1   40
#> 2   2 id2   2   40
#> 3   3 id1   2   40
#> 4   4 id2   3   30
#> 5   5 id1   1   30
#> 6   6 id2   3   30
#> 7   7 id1   3   20
#> 8   8 id2   2   20
#> 9   9 id1   2   20
#> 10 10 id2   1   10


# Mapping looks right, but the size may not be correct
plot_ly(df,
        x         = ~x,
        y         = ~y,
        color     = ~col,
        size      = ~size,
        type      = 'scatter',
        mode      = 'markers',
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text      = ~paste('</br> x: ',     x,
                           '</br> y: ',     y,
                           '</br> col: ',  col,
                           '</br> size: ', size)
        # , marker  = list(size = ~size)
        )
```

[image: plot1]

```
# Size looks right, but mapping to points is wrong
plot_ly(df,
        x         = ~x,
        y         = ~y,
        color     = ~col,
        # size      = ~size,
        type      = 'scatter',
        mode      = 'markers',
        hoverinfo = "text",
        text      = ~paste('</br> x: ',     x,
                           '</br> y: ',     y,
                           '</br> col: ',  col,
                           '</br> size: ', size)
        , marker  = list(size = ~size)
)
```

[image: plot2]

```
devtools::session_info()  # excerpt
#> plotly       * 4.8.0
```

Comment: The area is correctly mapped in your first attempt, but the area of the circles is mapped to the values. If you add `marker  = list(sizemode = "diameter")`, the circles will appear just like in the second attempt. Notice though: https://www.data-to-viz.com/caveat/radius_or_area.html